# export custom swift module

Tags: xcode, swift

I've made a little module in Swift and I want to use it in other projects. Do I have to simply copy the `name_of_module.a`, `name_of_module.swiftmodule` and `name_of_module.swiftdoc` files in the folder of the new project?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Swift packages and modules are used a bit differently than .frameworks did in Obj-C if that's what you've been using. Currently, modules are included via reference in your project's manifest file **Package.swift**.

This manifest file get called and dependencies' modules are used during .build (and by extension .debug).

The following is an example of a **package.swift** manifest file:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
name: "DeckOfPlayingCards",
targets: [],
dependencies: [
    .Package(url: "https://github.com/apple/example-package-fisheryates.git",
             majorVersion: 1),
    .Package(url: "https://github.com/apple/example-package-playingcard.git",
             majorVersion: 1),
    ]
)
```

Here the two dependencies (modules) are added to this project by a URL reference in *git* form.  If you're familiar with URL format, you can create a URL pointing to an address on your local machine of your local module rather than on github like the example above.

If you're concerned with sub-dependencies or want to learn more, read Apple's Swift docs on this (https://swift.org/package-manager/#conceptual-overview)